# How to apply date range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The example is my booking form but it's not date range and it is a [Pikaday datepicker plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) and I want to make it date-range and [I find out example](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/blob/master/examples/date-range.html) but didn't work

and here is my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
    minLength: 0,
    searchContain: true,
  }).on('select:flexdatalist', function() {
    $('#checkin').trigger("click");
  });

  assignPicker = function(id, whenClosed) {
    if (typeof whenClosed !== 'function') {
      whenClosed = null;
    }

    return new Pikaday({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      field: document.getElementById(id),
      format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
      minDate: new Date(),
      firstDay: 1,
      maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
      onSelect: whenClosed
    });
  }

  var checkoutPicker = assignPicker('checkout', function() {
    $('#select').trigger("click");
  });

  var checkinPicker = assignPicker('checkin', function() {
    var maxDate = this.getMoment().add(15, 'days');
    checkoutPicker.setMaxDate(maxDate.toDate());
    checkoutPicker.setMinDate(this.getDate());
    checkoutPicker.setDate(null);
  });

});
```

```css
 body {
     padding: 30px;
 }
 input, select {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/example/flexdatalist/flexdatalist.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="" class='flexdatalist' data-min-length='1' list='languages' name='language' />
        <datalist id="languages">
          <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
          <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
          <option value="Cobol">Cobol</option>
          <option value="C#">C#</option>
          <option value="C++">C++</option>
          <option value="Java">Java</option>
          <option value="Pascal">Pascal</option>
          <option value="FORTRAN">FORTRAN</option>
          <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
          <option value="Swift">Swift</option>
          <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        </datalist>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="checkin" id="checkin" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">

          <input type="text" class="checkout" id="checkout" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<form action="" method="get">
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="0">Choose</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/example/flexdatalist/flexdatalist.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zZOVWa)

Comment: I would recommend you to try this as well http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: thanks Saurabh this datepicker has been using in web site that is why we have to use pikaday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, So you are making a mistake in the picker.

As I see you are passing the `id` in your `assignPicker` and in between your further two functions `startPicker` and `endPicker` are inheriting the values passed in the `id`.

Which is causing the conflict, as whenever `startPicker` or `endPicker` is called, both get the `id` of the same dom object as `var id` (passed in the `assignPicker`) is common for both  `startPicker` or `endPicker`.

You need to separate them or just simply assign the `id` directly instead of passing it as an argument and fetching it inside the function.

```
startPicker = new Pikaday({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        field: document.getElementById("checkin"),
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
        onSelect: function() {
            startDate = this.getDate();
            updateStartDate();
        }
    }),
    endPicker = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById("checkout"),
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
        onSelect: function() {
            endDate = this.getDate();
            updateEndDate();
        }
    }),
```

That will fix the range for you.

Here's the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpZoeL)

Comment: yes I tried before but I can choose only `23` why ?

Comment: Because you are using `minDate: new Date(),` which initializes the picker with current date on your machine

Comment: ouuw..there was some function my checkin and checkout function it must 15 days two input

Comment: and thanks @Saurabh Sharma how can I remove minDAte: ? I have my own mindate

Comment: so how can I pick current and next day ?